# Haskell, "Couldn't match expected type" in function composition

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to write a simple function to check whether one integer divides another by taking the modulus and checking if it's 0. My thought was something like

```
divides :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
divides = (==0) . (flip mod)
```

where divides a b would be true iff a divides b. However, this code gives me the error

```
Couldn't match expected type `a -> Bool' with actual type `Bool'
Expected type: b0 -> a -> Bool
 Actual type: b0 -> Bool
In the first argument of `(.)', namely `(== 0)'
In the expression: (== 0) . mod
```

I really don't see why this code doesn't work. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 6):

The gist is, `.` will only feed each function 1 argument, but `flip mod` needs two. A simple solution is

```
(.:) = (.) . (.) -- the owl or boobs operator

divides = (0==) .: flip mod
```

where `.:` is

```
 (c -> d) -> (a -> b -> c) -> a -> b -> d
```

Answer (score 4):

To see what's wrong with your code, just eta-expand it manually:

```
divides :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
divides = (==0) . (flip mod)
-- divides x = ((==0) . (flip mod)) x
--           = ((==0) $ flip mod x)
--           = flip mod x == 0
```

That last line doesn't typecheck, because `(==) :: a -> a -> Bool`, but `divides x` should be of type `a -> Bool`, not `Bool`!

The easiest way to correct the code would be to write it in a more expanded form, for example:

```
divides :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
divides x = (==0) . (`mod` x)
```

If you really want to write it eta-reduced, here is what it would look like:

```
divides :: (Integral a) => a -> a -> Bool
divides = ((==0).) . (flip mod)
-- divides x = ((==0).) $ (`mod` x)
--           = (==0) . (`mod x`)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're expecting the `.` operator to carry over the fact that `flip mod` takes two arguments to its result, ie. you expect this:

```
f :: a -> b -> c
g :: c -> d
g . f :: a -> b -> d
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't work that way. Functions always take a single argument, and multiple argument functions are "simulated" by having functions that return a function. For ex, `a -> b -> c` can be read as `a -> (b -> c)`. Therefore what happens is as follows:

```
f :: a -> (b -> c)
g :: (b -> c) -> d
g . f :: a -> d
```

Thus why `g` (which is `(== 0)` in your case) expects a function, and the type of your function actually is `a -> Bool` and not `a -> a -> Bool`.